# UWP - cannot change placeholder text of CalendarDatePicker

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a `CalendarDatePicker` like this :

```
<CalendarDatePicker Grid.Row="10"
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        Name="BirthdayPicker"
                                        PlaceholderText="{x:Bind ViewModel._FORM_dob, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                 
                                        Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"
                                        DateFormat = "{}{year.full}-{month.integer}-{day.integer}"/>
```

I am unable to change its placeholder text. It always the placeholder that it gets the first time ( when the app starts ). after that `Bindings.Update()` does not change its placeholder text. I have also tried in the code behind:

```
BirthdayPicker.PlaceholderText = string.Empty;
 BirthdayPicker.PlaceholderText = ViewModel._FORM_dob;
 BirthdayPicker.MaxDate = DateTime.Now;
```

even this doesn't change the placeholder text. During debugging it shows the placeholder property has changed but it doesn't reflect in the UI

Comment: Sorry I couldn't test it, will do it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to bad design of the control's default styling.

Inside its [default style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299110.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), there's a `TextBlock` called `DateText` which is bound with `PlaceholderText` via `TemplateBinding`. However, this control is also used to display the selected `Date` string. By doing this, the binding between the `Text` and the `PlaceholderText` will be broken and that's why when you provide a different value for the latter, the change is not reflected on the UI.

The reason that I said it's bad design is because the placeholder text should never be used for displaying the date text. Instead, a separate `TextBlock` should be created for this purpose only. Users of the control should expect any *non-readonly* dependency properties to just work with bindings without worrying about them being broken by hidden code.

---

### Solution

So I have modified the default style a bit to include a new `TextBlock` just for displaying the `PlaceholderText` property. I removed the `TemplateBinding` from `DateText` and also changed its color along with some `Visibility` updates inside the `Selected` visual state.

Here is a full copy for your reference.

```
<Style TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarDatePicker">
                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DateText"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerTextForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CalendarGlyph"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForegroundDisabled}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background"
                                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                        Value="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerBackgroundFocused}" />
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Placeholder.(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                    Value="Collapsed" />
                                            <Setter Target="DateText.(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                    Value="Visible" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                                <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
                                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="Padding"
                                                    Value="0" />
                                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                                    Value="0" />
                                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                                        <ContentPresenter Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                                          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                                          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                    <CalendarView x:Name="CalendarView"
                                                  Style="{TemplateBinding CalendarViewStyle}"
                                                  MinDate="{TemplateBinding MinDate}"
                                                  MaxDate="{TemplateBinding MaxDate}"
                                                  IsTodayHighlighted="{TemplateBinding IsTodayHighlighted}"
                                                  DisplayMode="{TemplateBinding DisplayMode}"
                                                  FirstDayOfWeek="{TemplateBinding FirstDayOfWeek}"
                                                  DayOfWeekFormat="{TemplateBinding DayOfWeekFormat}"
                                                  CalendarIdentifier="{TemplateBinding CalendarIdentifier}"
                                                  IsOutOfScopeEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsOutOfScopeEnabled}"
                                                  IsGroupLabelVisible="{TemplateBinding IsGroupLabelVisible}" />
                                </Flyout>
                            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                              x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                              Margin="{ThemeResource ComboBoxHeaderThemeMargin}"
                                              Visibility="Collapsed"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                              TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            <Border x:Name="Background"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="DateText"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Foreground="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerTextForegroundSelected}"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       FontSize="15"
                                       Padding="12, 0, 0, 2"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="Placeholder"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       Foreground="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerTextForeground}"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                       Grid.Row="1"
                                       FontSize="15"
                                       Padding="12, 0, 0, 2"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <FontIcon x:Name="CalendarGlyph"
                                      Glyph="&#xE787;"
                                      FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource CalendarDatePickerCalendarGlyphForeground}"
                                      Grid.Row="1"
                                      Grid.Column="1"
                                      FontSize="16"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
</Style>
```